# 4x6 wood swingset beam, single span, center load max lbs?

Tags: structural, load-bearing, beam, lumber

I'm building a swing set with a 10 ft 4x6 pine beam.

I would like to determine how much active load the beam can support at the center point,  or at least minimally how much static load.

I've tried researching different online calculators but I'm not finding exactly what I'm looking for a.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The best you'll get is a range because wood is a natural product and any two 4x6's will have different breaking points. That said, take a look at swing-set kits sold at local big-box stores or by your local swing-set specialists. You'll get an idea of the max span you can expect based on what they use.

Comment: Why?   Are you putting something right in the center?   It is good to understand why you need to know this.   If you are installing two swings over the 10' you could have 2 300 pound males and it wouldn't hurt a 4x6.

Comment: Or females. Related: [1](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/125659/what-is-the-working-load-limit-of-a-18-foot-4x6-pine-beam), [2](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/94054/beam-size-and-material-for-15-feet-long-swing), [3](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/49086/is-this-swing-beam-safe), [4](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/168768/can-i-use-a-4x6x16-top-beam-for-a-cantilevered-swing-set/168770#168770)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forte Web is an excellent tool for designing wood beams.

That being said, it can take a point live load at mid-span of 610 pounds. Make sure you purchase #1 or select structural. You don't want any knots in the beam because of the types of forces a swing will apply to it.

[image]